# Typescript Inference for Pipeable Function

Tags: typescript, generics, filter, functional-programming, pipe

I'm developing a class that wraps an Array and creates a pipeable filter function.

However, Typescript inference does not work for the predicate function. I assume it has to do with generic scoping, is there a way to workaround this limitation?

```js
class SomeClass<T> {
    constructor(public arr: Array<T>) {}
}

function filter <R> (fn: (r: R) => boolean) {
    return function (obj: SomeClass<R>) : SomeClass<R> {
        return new SomeClass(obj.arr.filter(fn));
    }
} 

/* How to replace i: unknown with i: number? */
let r = filter (i => i > 2) (new SomeClass([1, 2, 3]))
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the generic type to the function, also you need to initialize some property with the constructor, or else just change the `SomeClass` to an array of some generic `T`.

like this:

```
class SomeClass<T> {
    constructor(public arr: Array<T>) {}
}

function filter <R> (fn: (r: R) => boolean) {
    return function (obj: SomeClass<R>) : SomeClass<R> {
        return new SomeClass(obj.arr.filter(fn));
    }
} 

/* How to replace i: unknown with i: number? */
let r = filter<number>(i => i >= 2) (new SomeClass([1, 2, 3]))
console.log(r);
```